# Unique solution to normal equation proof

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares

So I'm trying to prove the following:

> Show that a unique solution for linear regression exists i the features are not linearly dependent. Namely,show that a unique solution $argmin_{\theta} (X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y$
> exists iff $X$ has full column rank.

What I did was:

Theorem: For every matrix $A\in R^{nxm}$ we have $Null(A) = Null(A^{T}A)$ and $Rank(A) = Rank(A^{T}A)$

then I said:
if $(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}$ is a solution $\rightarrow$ $(X^{T}X)^{-1}$ is invertible $\rightarrow$
$Null(A^{T}A)=\{0\}$ $\rightarrow$ $Null(A) = \{0\}$ $\rightarrow$ $A$ is full rank

But I'm not sure this is the right way, also the opposite direction seems identical(reversed) to the one I wrote.

Would appreciate some help

### Edit

So I derived the following expression for the normal equation through the derivation of the MSE loss:

$(X^{T}X)\theta = X^{T}y$

So $\theta$ is the parameter I used to derive with, and $X,y$ are the "training set"

So I want to prove now that the solution for $\theta$ that minimize the loss is unique given $X$ is full rank.

Comment: What is the relationship between $\theta,X,$ and $y$?

Comment: Also, what does it mean to "minimize" the expression $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$? It makes sense to minimize a scalar, but not to minimize a vector

Comment: @BenGrossmann I added some more details, let me know if things still missing.

Comment: Ok, so what you're really asking about is the uniqueness of $\text{argmin}_\theta \|X \theta - y\|$

Comment: [Relevant if not identical](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205325/is-the-least-square-estimator-unique/205329#205329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right basic ideas, but the way you write things doesn't quite make sense. I would argue that the following statements are all equivalent:

- There is a unique solution to $\text{argmin}_\theta\|X\theta - y\|$,
- There is a unique solution to $X^TX \theta = X^Ty$,
- $X^TX$ is invertible,
- $X^TX$ has full rank,
- $X$ has full column rank.

Indeed, these steps make sense in both the forward and backward directions.

Comment: Oh I see, so aside from not writing it properly, the basic Idea I had was right isn't it?